# Removing a Sprites Color Key libGDX

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

I am trying to remove the color key from a sprite. In this case my sprite backgrounds are purple. I have tried using the spritebatch setColor() function, but that turns the whole screen to the sprites background color. does anyone have a solution on how to remove the color?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

I don't think libGDX (or OpenGL ES) support "colorkey" transparency.  As far as I know, everyone just uses an alpha (transparency) channel in the image.  (In addition to red, green blue, each pixel has an alpha value representing its transparency.)

If you remove the background color in an offline tool and save the image with transparency information you should be fine.  (And I believe this is what most existing libGDX apps do.)

Alternatively, you can probably do this at runtime by defining a shader that converts colorkey pixels into transparent pixels.

Comment: I have removed the background from the image in Paint.Net. I always did that when doing anything with Slick2D, it always worked fine but for some reason it's not working with libGDX.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the background purple or not?  Are you saving the image in a format that preserves transparency?  If your image is stored with transparency information (i.e., an alpha channel) then you're having problems at render time.  Blending should be enabled by default, though ...

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more clear. What I do when I create a sprite is, I set the background to purple, draw the sprite and then remove the purple background with the magic wand tool.Then save it and import the sprite to my assets folder for the game